# Password protection screen on ios is delayed when resuming the app

Tags: ios, background, notifications, passwords, resume

I'm trying to write a simple password protection screen, but I've noticed that hooking into the didEnterBackground and willEnterForeground have a delay, and you can still see the screen contents for a brief second or so before I get the notification and am able to add the password screen on top. The scenario I want is:

1. App enters background, add subview to the front so it is on top
2. App resumes, password window is already on top

It almost seems like you can't do any window operations (like addSubview) during these notifications. Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add the password screen earlier, but make it hidden, and not interacting with the user? i.e., set the `hidden` and `userInteractionEnabled` properties to TRUE and FALSE, respectively? Then in `willEnterForeground`, unhide it and enable user interaction?

Comment: I'll see if this works, that's a good idea. It's possible that something is going on with the self.window at that point and I can't add subviews to it so maybe this solution will work, since it already is a subview and we're just unhiding it.

Comment: Worked well thanks! This has no lag if I call during willEnterForeground.